# bigquery type check operator? like typeof in Javascript; or workaround

Tags: google-bigquery

in a project where the BigQuery table's schema constantly evolves, I wonder is there a good way to write SQL code in generic?

for example, a feature flag field in version 1 was a simple BOOLEAN, but later on evolved to a FLOAT to represent values between 0 (false) and 1 (true), then later changed to a STRUCT of multiple BOOLEANs,
for every schema revision I changed table name as well, so now I have current table v3 and the old table v2 and v1 as well, the old tables have historical information is still useful sometimes, and volume is big not good to migrate all into v3 schema; since bigquery is mostly used as load-once and then append-only, or most cases read-only database, just query from old tables is good enough;
with table name wildcards I can query all of the tables in a single query, but not sure how to handle the different input types, is there a dynamic type checking function to write the query SQL like this `typeof` operator in Javascript: ?

```
CASE typeof feature
  WHEN "BOOLEAN" THEN ... # handle v1
  WHEN "FLOAT"   THEN ... # handle v2
  WHEN "STRUCT"  THEN ... # handle v3
  WHEN ...
  ELSE
END
```

or what would you suggest to work around? if the project's nature has an constantly evolving schema (because of fast moving requirement or many other common reasons)

Answer (score 10):

[`FORMAT('%T', obj)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions?hl=en#format_format_string) transforms any typed value to a literal string.
It can be used to implement `typeof` function in SQL UDF.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION typeof_literal(input STRING)
AS (
      CASE
        -- Process NUMERIC, DATE, DATETIME, TIME, TIMESTAMP,
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(input, r'^[A-Z]+ "') THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(input, r'^([A-Z]+) "')
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(input, r'^-?[0-9]*$') THEN 'INT64'
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(input, r'^(-?[0-9]+[.e].*|CAST\("([^"]*)" AS FLOAT64\))$') THEN 'FLOAT64'
        WHEN input IN ('true', 'false') THEN 'BOOL'
        WHEN input LIKE '"%' THEN 'STRING'
        WHEN input LIKE 'b"%' THEN 'BYTES'
        WHEN input LIKE '[%' THEN 'ARRAY'
        WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(input, r'^(STRUCT)?\(') THEN 'STRUCT'
        WHEN input LIKE 'ST_%' THEN 'GEOGRAPHY'
        WHEN input = 'NULL' THEN 'NULL'
      ELSE
      'UNKNOWN'
    END );

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION typeof(input ANY TYPE)
AS ( typeof_literal(FORMAT('%T', input)) );

-- You can pass any type value to typeof function
SELECT typeof(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
-- result: "TIMESTAMP"
SELECT typeof(STRUCT(1, 2, 3));
-- result: "STRUCT"
```

Exhaustive tests and result are placed in [gist](https://gist.github.com/apstndb/71b9a119ee16ffc4598e0af32678e4fe) because it is too long.

### Update

You can use community-based public UDF [`bqutil.fn.typeof`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#typeofinput-any-type).

```
CASE bqutil.fn.typeof(feature)
  WHEN "BOOLEAN" THEN ... # handle v1
  WHEN "FLOAT"   THEN ... # handle v2
  WHEN "STRUCT"  THEN ... # handle v3
  WHEN ...
  ELSE
END
```

Note: BigQuery does type check before query execution so expression in `THEN` clause must be valid in all `WHEN-THEN` pairs.

Answer (score 1):

> or what would you suggest to work around?

So, to rephrase your idea - you are thinking about UNION ALL from different tables with different schema. Unfortunately, this is not going to fly because of different schemas!

I recommend below workaround:
You will need to create a views for each version to make schema of each view the same. See below as an example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH table_v1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, TRUE AS feature UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, FALSE AS feature 
),
table_v2 AS (
  SELECT 3 AS id, 0.2 AS feature UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 0.8 AS feature 
),
table_v3 AS (
  SELECT 5 AS id, STRUCT<x BOOL, y bool, z bool>(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) AS feature UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS id, (TRUE, TRUE, TRUE) AS feature 
),
view_v1 AS (
  SELECT id, feature 
  FROM table_v1  
),
view_v2 AS ( 
  SELECT id, CASE WHEN feature < 0.5 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS feature -- handle v2
  FROM table_v2 
),
view_v3 AS (
  SELECT id, feature.x OR feature.y OR feature.z AS feature -- handle v3
  FROM table_v3
),
table_all AS (
  SELECT * FROM view_v1 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM view_v2 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM view_v3 
)
SELECT *
FROM table_all
WHERE feature
-- ORDER BY id
```

When you will have your views saved - you will be able to use wildcards  against those views

Comment: it's a nice workaround; while I know here has some google employees who works for bigquery backend is watching here, can we suggest Google to add a `typeof` operator like I suggested above?
 through https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=reporter:<my-email> I suggested some features to google some were taken and become true