# BigQuery: is there a generic function which extracts & converts a scalar value in json

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I'm starting working on json columns in google bigquery.

My aim is to implement a query which: extracts a given value in the json object based on path and returns its real SQL value.

Example: given `{"foo": {"bar": 123}}`, I'd like to get the `$.foo.bar` value as integer.
But, when querying the table containing json column I get a string.
I do understand this behavior is well documented.
I'm searching for a snippet / recipe / a way to implement something that would do the scalar casting for me.

I got to something which is not valid SQL, but represents what I search for:

```sql
WITH
  base AS (
  SELECT
    JSON_QUERY( JSON '{"foo": {"unknown":123}}', '$.foo') AS col)
SELECT
  CASE JSON_TYPE(JSON_QUERY(col, '$.unknown'))
    WHEN 'null' THEN NULL
    WHEN 'number' THEN LAX_FLOAT64(JSON_QUERY(col, '$.unknown'))
    WHEN 'boolean' THEN LAX_BOOL(JSON_QUERY(col, '$.unknown'))
    WHEN 'string' THEN LAX_STRING(JSON_QUERY(col, '$.unknown'))
  ELSE
  -- array or map are not scalar - keep them as they are:
  JSON_QUERY(col, '$.unknown')
END as output
FROM
  base
```

Any help is highly appreciated! THANKS :)

Comment: `CASE` can only return one data type

Answer (score 0):

**Query**:

In your query `output` column [expecting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions) only one data type,so instead of creating one column you can consider the below query:

```
select  *, if(type="string",LAX_STRING(col),null) stringcolumn, if(type="number",LAX_FLOAT64(col),null) intcolumn, if(type="boolean",LAX_BOOL(col),null) boolcolumn, from (select *,json_type(col)as type from base);
```

**Result:**

[image]

From the above result,you can select the column that does not contain null values. For example if your input value is number then column
stringcolumn and boolcolumn value is null. Using a subquery instead of selecting all columns you can select the  intcolumn column.

Based on my understanding  there is no builtin BigQuery function that extracts an exact given value in the json object based on the path and returns its real SQL value. So If you want this feature in BigQuery, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

For more information you can refer to these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730045/),[link2](https://medium.com/google-cloud/working-with-json-data-in-bigquery-24ca8fd6e90c) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59804851/bigquery-select-column-only-if-not-null).